# How can I limit the CPU usage when encoding h264 with libavcodec?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, encoding, libav, libavcodec

I encode raw images to h264 video and set up my encoder parameters like this before calling `avocdec_open2()`:

```
void set_codec_params(AVFormatContext *&fctx, AVCodecContext *&codec_ctx,
                      double width, double height, int fps) {
  const AVRational dst_fps = {fps, 1};

  codec_ctx->codec_tag = 0;
  codec_ctx->bit_rate = target_bitrate;
  codec_ctx->thread_count = 1; // <----- does nothing
  codec_ctx->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
  codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
  codec_ctx->width = width;
  codec_ctx->height = height;
  codec_ctx->gop_size = 12;
  codec_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
  codec_ctx->framerate = dst_fps;
  codec_ctx->time_base = av_inv_q(dst_fps);
  if (fctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
    codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
  }
}
```

I set profile parameters like this

```
  AVDictionary *codec_options = nullptr;
  av_dict_set(&codec_options, "profile", "high", 0);
  av_dict_set(&codec_options, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
  av_dict_set(&codec_options, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
```

No matter what I do, all cores are maxed out during encoding, but I would like to limit this to some number of threads. The `thread_count` structure member seems to be ignored.

Generally, what steps can be taken to limit the number of threads used for encoding? Do some settings conflict with a user-defined thread count?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you use x264 as h264 encoder.

The `AVCodecContex` is a general struct for all existing codecs. So setting some attributes will have no effect if the selected encoder doesn't support it. Adjusting the thread count, however, is a setting that most encoders should support. Nevertheless, some settings will still be ignored or overwritten. In such cases you need to set them by using the `AVDictionary`:

```
av_dict_set(&codec_options, "threads", "1", 0);
```